# How to disable varnish?

Tags: cache, varnish

I have to work on Magento and which uses Varnish cache.

How do I disable it? Or is there a way to see changes immediately?

Front End  showing:

> Error 503 Backend fetch failed Backend fetch failed
>
> Guru Meditation: XID: 32840
>
> Varnish cache server

Comment: Depends on your Varnish configuration and which Magento extension you use for Varnish. Or are you working with Magento 2? Without more details there is no definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Turpentine? If so, you can use the *Varnish Bypass* option under *Cache Managemnent* to bypass Varnish altogether.

If not, Varnish is generally set up to access Magento via apache/nginx running on a particular port. If you can find out what that port is and access it directly, you should be able to access the site directly w/out going through Varnish.

A final option would be to alter the VCL that Varnish is using such that it just passes all request from your IP address directly through without a cache lookup.